# MSAccess 2013 Weekly Report

Tags: report, ms-access-2013, weekday

I try to make a weekly report on Access 2013.  This must show in columns the week days from Tuesday to current Monday and if it begins the month should show from the first day until current Tuesday. In this way if the user selects the entire month the report should show the four columns weeks.

My table only contain the entities `Sum([TotalCalls]) (Items)` and `[BeginTime] (Period)`

Report Display Example for Jan 2016 Needed:

```
Clmn1  Clmn2  Clmn3  Clmn4  Clmn5
 1/4    5/11  12/18  19/25  26/31
```

I made a normal weekly report but this is not the way in which it is used. I don't know how to create any formula to display in columns this.

I appreciate any help in learning. Thanks!

Comment: I have a result with this formula in the corsstab column: PIVOT Format([BeginTime]+7-Weekday([BeginTime],3),"ww",2,2) In (1,2,3,4,5); and display in the selected range from tuesday to monday.

Comment: Now I need to work with labels in the report to show weeks like 1/4, 5/11, but in this is different because it must be with the date of the selection that comes from the form where the user enters the date. Any Healp in this I will appreciate.